# SFML RectangleShape won't render

Tags: c++, rendering, sfml

I have a `sf::RectangleShape` in my code which is defined like this :

```
sf::RectangleShape shape_1;
```

And it's values are set like this :

```
shape_1.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
shape_1.setPosition(10, 10);
```

But when I render it like this :

```
    window.draw(shape_1);
```

It wont display in my window.

---

My rendering part of the code looks like this :

```
    window.clear();

    window.draw(*box.getSfShape());
    window.draw(*box_static.getSfShape());
    window.draw(shape_1);

    window.display();
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Have been going on for days thinking it was a position problem with a body but since this won't render either it can't be. :P

Comment: You'll have to show more code. Where do you set the shape's dimensions? Do you set them at all? The code you're showing looks fine as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the size of the rectangle with [setSize](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0-fr/classsf_1_1RectangleShape.php#a5c65d374d4a259dfdc24efdd24a5dbec).

```
shape_1.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100.f, 100.f));
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that.... Thank you ^-^